# Merge multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Dataframe 1:

```
name_a name_b name_c type
a      b      c      type_a
a      b      c      
a      b      c      
a      b      c      type_a
a      b      c
```

Dataframe 2:

```
name_a name_b name_c type
a      b      c      
a      b      c      
a      b      c      type_b
a      b      c      
a      b      c
```

Dataframe 3:

```
name_a name_b name_c type
a      b      c      
a      b      c      type_c
a      b      c      
a      b      c  
a      b      c
```

Output:

```
name_a name_b name_c type
a      b      c      type_a
a      b      c      type_c
a      b      c      type_b
a      b      c      type_a
a      b      c
```

Hello, is there a way for this output? I tried concatenated all the Dataframe with axis=0 so it will stack the Dataframe vertically, used index.name = "id" and reset_index(inplace=True) so i can identify its id.

```
id name_a name_b name_c type
0  a      b      c      type_a
1  a      b      c      
2  a      b      c      
3  a      b      c      type_a
4  a      b      c      
0  a      b      c      
1  a      b      c      
2  a      b      c      type_b
3  a      b      c      
4  a      b      c      
0  a      b      c      
1  a      b      c      type_c
2  a      b      c      
3  a      b      c      
4  a      b      c
```

Then i'm planning to groupby by id and retain the type column that has values but i can't figure it out, is there a way to merge the dataframe without using many methods or you have something another in mind that will work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Thanks. it's not actually solve all of it but with this, its a start. Solved it!